# Arr.map differs from Array.from for an array with no values

Tags: javascript

I always assumed `Array.from` behaves the same as `Array.map` for array. But it seems that for array with no initial values, they are totally different.

```
arr = new Array(5); 
range = Array.from(arr, (v,idx) => idx); // [0,1,2,3,4]
new_arr = arr.map((v, idx) => {return idx;}); // [undefined, undefined,undefined, undefined,undefined]
```

So `Array.from` was still able to get the indices, while `arr.map` here just skips through all the values, actually it never calls the callback function.

How does JavaScript handles an array with no initial values?

Answer (score 6):

`new Array(5)` creates a [sparse array](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch07s03.html), that is an array with a `length` of `5` but actually no entries - the elements 0-4 are not just `undefined`, they actually *don't exist*. (`0 in arr === false`)

You are writing above that the result of `map` is `[undefined, undefined, ...]` but actually it is another sparse array with no elements. In Chrome Devtools, you'd see this as `[empty × 5]` instead.

`Array.from` specifically has the purpose to create a regular array out of array-like things. It basically checks for a `length` property and creates a new array out of whatever is returned from `[0]`, `[1]`, ..., `[length - 1]`. Therefore, it turns the sparse array into a dense array with 5x `undefined` in it, and your callback is called for elements 0-4.

`Array.prototype.map` however just iterates over the (existing!) elements in the array and returns a new array with the mapped values. Note that the sparse array *has no elements*, hence your callback is never called, and the returned array looks the same as before.

Comment: *callback is never called* - you can see this by doing `new_arr = arr.map((v, idx) => {console.log('map', idx); return idx;});` vs `Array.from(arr, (v,idx) => { console.log('from', idx); return idx;});`

Answer (score 3):

The `Array.from()` method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object. It will not care if the array values are assigned or not it will just create a new array from the given array.

`Array.map` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array **which have assigned values**; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which **have never been assigned** values." In this case, `arr's` values have not explicitly assigned values, so map is not iterating over this array.

Difference of `Array.from` and `Array.map`.

`Array.from` is used to create a new array from an existing `array-like` like object.

And the `Array.map` is used to manipulate the array values if values are assigned.

Comment: you haven't explained why Array.from map callback is different :p

Comment: The simple difference is "Array.from is used to create a new array from an existing array-like like object" and the Array.map is used to manipulate the array values if values are assigned