# Replacing empty/undefined values with nulls in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to convert the empty/undefined values to null. I have tried the following:

```js
let arr = []
arr[1] = 2
arr[7] = 10
arr = arr.map(x => x || null)

console.log(arr)
```

But the output of the snippet is not as desired:

```
[
  undefined,
  2,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  10
]
```

How do I replace these undefined values with nulls?

Note: Both vanilla JS and Lodash answers are acceptable.

Comment: Related, but not (I don't think) a duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584217/arr-map-differs-from-array-from-for-an-array-with-no-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have will work for an array that has `undefined` elements in it, but not for a sparse array with holes in it, because [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't visit the holes in a sparse array; instead, the resulting array just has holes in the same places.

If you want to map the holes as well, you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)  with its mapping callback:

```js
let arr = [];
arr[1] = 2;
arr[7] = 10;
arr = Array.from(arr, x => x || null);

console.log(arr);
```

Unlike `map`, `Array.from` will go through all indexes of the array, including holes, passing `undefined` as `x` for the holes in the array to the mapping callback.

Another option is a simple `for-of` loop, because iteration visits holes in sparse arrays (which is why `Array.from` works above):

```js
let arr = [];
arr[1] = 2;
arr[7] = 10;
const newArr = [];
for (const value of arr) {
    newArr.push(value || null);
}
arr = newArr;

console.log(arr);
```

---

Note that `x || null` will replace **all** [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values with `null` (including `0` and `""`, which often trips people up). To just replace `undefined`, use `x ?? null` instead:

```js
let arr = [];
arr[1] = 2;
arr[7] = 10;
arr = Array.from(arr, x => x ?? null);

console.log(arr);
```

or

```js
let arr = [];
arr[1] = 2;
arr[7] = 10;
const newArr = [];
for (const value of arr) {
    newArr.push(value ?? null);
}
arr = newArr;

console.log(arr);
```

`x ?? y` ([nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)) is like `x || y` but only uses `y` if `x` evaluates to `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something very basic:

```
let arr = [];
arr[1] = 2; arr[7] = 10;
for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    if(!arr[i]) arr[i]=null;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
[
  null, 2,    null,
  null, null, null,
  null, 10
]
```

Comment: Also a useful option, though beware that this does two things differently than the OP seems to want. 1. It modifies the existing array rather than building a new one. 2. It replaces **all** falsy values with `null` (including `0` and `""` and `NaN`, etc.), not just `undefined` ones or holes.